# Will upvotes count for tag badge progress, even though I've reached rep cap for today?

Tags: discussion, badges, daily-reputation-limit

I have reached the rep cap for today, I understand that my reputation cannot go any further (with exception to accepted answers).  However what I am curious about is how it affects the badges I can earn?

For instance, my C# stats currently stands at 354. If my C# answers are being up voted during my phase of exceeding the reputation cap, does this also stop votes towards this badge or does it take into account any additional votes even though I have hit the cap?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Upvotes are not capped, only the reputation is capped.

Upvotes on your answers still count towards your tag badges.